# I’m trying to connect RabbitMQ server externally deployed. RabbitMQ client is deployed into GKE and communicates as SSL. SSL connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, google-kubernetes-engine, egress, rabbitmq.client

I’m trying to connect RabbitMQ server externally deployed. RabbitMQ client is deployed into GKE and communicates as SSL. Cluster is configured as kubedns , however I have cloud dns configured and rabbitmq server is configured by that. I tried to do test with OpenSSL with rabbit mq certs (leaf+intermediate + root) , it hangs after write hello. But when I do it locally the same ssl connection I could connect to it. What should I do to make connection in this case? Do I need to egress ssl traffic to specific reserved internal ip of cloud dns ?

rabbitmq client connection gets hanged  when it is calling factory.create connection(). On debugging with OpenSSL I could find the ssl issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the creation of a connection is hanging, it likely indicates a network issue. To diagnose, test network connectivity by using ping or telnet to reach the RabbitMQ endpoint on port 5672, and ensure that the egress configurations are properly established.